# Can't get clearInterval to work, despite several approaches

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have the following javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var intervalCounter = setInterval(function(){

    [... CODE HERE ...]

    if (i >= (arrayLength - 1)) {
        clearInterval(intervalCounter);
    } 

    else {
        i++;
    }
}, 200);
```

But, (you've guessed it), `clearInterval(intervalCounter);` doesn't clear the interval.

I could understand this, if the `if` condition were

```
if (i === (arrayLength - 1))
```

but how can the javascript engine repeatedly miss that `i` is greater than `(arrayLength-1)`?

Comment: I understand that clearInterval must be a major stumbling block, because a lot of javascript learners seem stumble over it. I've already searched SO and can't find any question that relates precisely, but if I've missed one, please give me a heads up and I'll delete this question. Many thanks.

Comment: What are you initializing i to? And what is the value of arrayLength? I suspect the problem lies in one of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works correctly, displaying 0 through 9 on the console:

```
var a = Array (10), 
    i = 0, 
    intervalCounter = setInterval(function(){
        console.log (i);
        if (i >= (a.length - 1)) {
           clearInterval(intervalCounter);
        } 
        else {
          i++;
        }
    }, 200);
```

Your problem must be with the value of `i` or `arrayLength`, try displaying those variables at each iteration

Comment: Confirming that the script was essentially valid and that the problem was with either of the two variables being checked helped me a long way to finding the solution - that there was a third variable I had failed to take into account (see my answer below). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer lay elsewhere, further down the script - I'll include it for the sake of completeness.

From various tests, it looked like the error had something to do with speed of script execution. The script controls a fast animation which occurs on page load, so I changed the event listener from

```
window.addEventListener('load',activateAnimation,false);
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',activateAnimation,false);
```

That enabled the animation to start sooner - and for more of the animation to work before it failed - but it didn't fix the problem - the `setInterval` was still running and hitting blanks infinitely after a certain number of runs.

Then it occurred to me that *because* the animation is taking place within a live `nodelist`... maybe the *next* part of the script (which removes elements from that `nodelist`) was starting too soon, leaving the `setInterval` still trying to work on `nodelist` elements that were no longer present in the document.

My solution was to increase the `setTimeOut` to create a bigger delay before the next part of the script commenced, but *also* to add an additional `clearInterval` as the top line of the script running within the `setInterval`:

```
if ((i + 1) > elements.length) {clearInterval(enterHashtag);}
```

That way, not only would the `setInterval` clear itself if the counter reached the end of the `nodelist`'s initial length, but it would also clear itself if the *next part of the script* had just removed from the `nodelist` the element the `setInterval` was about to go to work on.